# Indexing instances of different values in a python/pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm fairly new to python and I'm trying to automate a task to count instances of multiple values (student absence types) and then spit them back out on a single line per student.  If I have a single value, I can accomplish that by:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('attendanceUAnumbersLISTONLY.csv', header=0)
  
nf=df['StudentId'].value_counts()
print(nf)
nf.to_csv('studentua.csv', index=True, header=False)
```

The dataframe I'm pulling is a cognos report that simply shows a student ID number for each instance of an unexcused absence.  The underlying dataset looks like:

| StudentID | AbsenceType |
| --- | --- |
| 123456 | UA |
| 123456 | UA |
| 654321 | UA |

I ultimately want the output to be:

| StudentID | Count |
| --- | --- |
| 123456 | 2 |
| 654321 | 1 |

That code above will do that.  But if I want to pull values besides UA and put those into a different column of the output, that's where I'm stuck.  So if I have values of P (present), I want to export them out in a new column that I can import into another system.

| StudentID | UA | P |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123456 | 2 | 7 |
| 654321 | 1 | 8 |

I can't get my head around how to do that.

Comment: From what I understand from your question, you if you want to aggregate more than 1 column, I suggest using the df.groupby().agg() method. In your case, it would be something like **df.groupby("StudentID").agg("sum")** or  **df.groupby("StudentID").agg("count")** if you wanted the row counts instead of the sum

Answer (score 0):

What about first [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) using both columns, then [`size`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) to get the number of occurences, [`unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) to pivot the level index level of `AbsenceType` and [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) to fill where no occurences are found:

```
df.groupby(['StudentId', 'AbsenceType']).size().unstack(level=1).fillna(0)
```